# Accessing ethernet ip from wifi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routes, webserver

I am running a web server that is running on 10.42.0.1:5000 on a linux machine and I can access and communicate with the web server from another machine/phone by connecting to the hotspot created by the linux machine. I have another 3rd party server that is running on another device and is connected to my linux machine via ethernet and I can access that server from the linux machine @ 192.168.1.201

I would like to provide a bridge through my web server so that I can access 192.168.1.201 through my web server.

How do I proceed to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a static route to your system. 

The syntax is pretty simple:

```
ip route add {NETWORK/MASK} via {GATEWAYIP}
ip route add {NETWORK/MASK} dev {DEVICE}
ip route add default {NETWORK/MASK} dev {DEVICE}
ip route add default {NETWORK/MASK} via {GATEWAYIP}
```

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ip-route-add-network-command-for-linux-explained/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22092460)

Comment: Thanks for this hint, didn't think about that